# What is the best move in this position?

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to make a correct move but I can't find one.

When I move, I always get a warning message from chess.com.

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "12.29.2021"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Fmbalbuena"]
[Black "AI (600 ELO)"]
[Result "*"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "2r1k3/p2np1b1/1qp1bnpr/1p1p1pN1/1P1P1P1P/N1P1P3/P2R2QR/2B1KB2 w - - 0 1"]
```

update from OPs comment: In the board, it's whites turn to play.

Comment: @Marco i play white

Comment: This is white turn

Comment: @Marco Error means That i will lose, Not invalid move.

Comment: WHY THE QUESTION GOT CLOSED?????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132713/discussion-between-fmbalbuena-and-marco).

Answer (score 1):

> When I move, I always get Error of chess.com, Why?
> Error means That i will lose, Not invalid move.

Nxe6 is winning. You take a piece for free and threaten another piece. Meanwhile black has no threats.

```
[FEN "2r1k3/p2np1b1/1qp1bnpr/1p1p1pN1/1P1P1P1P/N1P1P3/P2R2QR/2B1KB2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Nxe6
```

Comment: Nxe6 is short for kNight takes on e6. Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess) if required.